# Inputting an arithmatic statement in c and return the value

Tags: c, string

(I am very bad at inputting/processing strings in `C`. Hope this question will teach me a lot.)

I am trying to make a function that will input an arithmatic string from `stdin`, e.g `23 + 45 * 6 - 5`, and return the value.

There are multiple strings, entered one after another, and can be of any length and the operator precedence doesn't matter, i.e., it processes string sequentially.

The problems that I faced are :-

1. `\n` from previous string is also considered a string.So if I input 3 strings , it will actually be 6, 3 strings and 3 `\n`.
2. I used a char pointer and used `char * input; scanf(" %s",input);`, but in addition to above problem, I also get segmentation fault, which I guess is due to missing `\0`.

My question is forget what mess I did, what would you have done or what's the best way to handle string input in the above scenario. A dummy code is sufficient.Thanks.

**What I was doing**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t; //no of test cases
    char input;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        while((input=getchar())!='\n')
        {
            //use switch to identify char and follow appropriate action 
            printf("%c\n",input );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You won't get the code for free here. Show what you tried and we will point out mistakes.

Comment: If you use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) then the newline will be in the buffer for the *current* line. As it's last, it's easy to remove (replace with the terminator).

Comment: The question is unclear (especially without showing your code), but if you're inputting a string with spaces you should use `fgets` and not `scanf`.

Comment: Also, the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format `"%s"` *skips* leading whitespace, so if you're using that format then that should not be the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8124994/971127 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8067449/971127

Comment: Read every line with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) then code your own [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser), probably coding your own [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Joachim Pileborg, use `fgets`. Use a char array, instead of one `char` variable, to store the string.

```
char input[100];
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
```

The advantage of `fgets` over `sscanf` is that `fgets` can read spaces in your input.

It will include the end-of-line byte `\n`, so 3 strings will not turn into 6 strings.

As usual with `fgets`, there is an arbitrary limit on the length of the input. If the user inputs something longer than 98 bytes, the system cannot fit it all (plus end-of-line `\n` and end-of-string `\0` bytes), and the program will receive truncated string.

If you cannot tolerate that, use [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) (it's harder to use, so use `fgets` if in doubt).

Comment: I would suggest the opposite: use `getline` and if you cannot use it, downgrade to `fgets` with a quite big line buffer (e.g. at least 256 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

After you scan your string in, check to see if it is a '\n', if it is just ignore processing it and move to the next one.

Or you could try:

```
char input[101];
scanf("%s\n", &input);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all. Your idea of writing an fomular expression analyzer as a first projekt is not a very good one. Start with a simpler project.

You get the sagmentation fault, because you try to read data (with the scanf()) into a not initialized pointer.

char *input;

will not allocate any memory for the string you want to read with scanf(). You have to use a buffer something like

char input[256];

and give the pointer to the buffer to scanf("%s",input) (oder for better understanding scanf("%s",&input[0]);

Anywhere, this buffer has only 255 chars to store and you must be aware, that if you enter more then 255 chars in the scanf() you will get an illegal memory access as well.

Claus